# Version problem of Chrome Tabs Client of TWA Android apps

Tags: android-studio, progressive-web-apps, twa

I have a TWA android app and I am trying to add a splash screen flowing instructions from here:
https://dev.to/henrylim96/adding-splash-screen-to-trusted-web-activity-48p3

As mentioned, I have to use an updated version of Chrome Tabs Client that able to check from here:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/custom-tabs-client/+log

my current version is d08e93fce3 so in my build.gradle it is like this:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'com.github.GoogleChrome.custom-tabs-client:customtabs:d08e93fce3'
  ...
}
```

I tried 809a55c which is the latest, 700d2e1 and 3679335 which is mentioned on the website, 
all make the app crash on all my devices.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Hey did you tried the default version from the [TWA-Getting-Started-Site](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa)?
I would write a comment but i cant. So if you have not tried it yet this could help.

Code:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'com.google.androidbrowserhelper:androidbrowserhelper:1.0.0'
  ...
}
```